# Lichbane Proc Damage on Statchanging Spells

Tags: league-of-legends

From official Site, Taric Champ info:

> Taric slams his hammer into the ground, dealing 150/250/350 (+70% Ability Power) magic damage to nearby enemies.For the next 10 seconds, Taric's gems radiate energy, granting him 30/50/70 Attack Damage and Ability Power and his nearby allies half of the bonuses.

simple question:

Building Lichbane, which damage will be done by lichbane proc when ultimate activates Lichbane?

the AP before cast or the AP after cast ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The damage of Lich Bane's proc is determined by your AP at the moment that you attack and consume the buff. Whatever AP you have when you consume the buff, that's how much bonus damage Lich Bane will do.

Comment: A side note that may be useful in other scenarios; Damage calculation in LoL is done at the instant the damage is inflicted on an enemy not when it was cast.

Comment: Correct Brian, if Teemo puts down a trap and Teemo levels up his Trap-skill a minute later, the trap will deal the damage according to the upgraded stats!